# Relative position needing -px

Tags: html, css, positioning

When i set my footer to relative it drops off the page and end up needing -1800px to get it to the bottom of the content but that then leaves a massive white space at the bottom what can cause this to happen? And what can you do to fix it?

```
      #footer {
      background-image: url(http://***.***.***.*/spvfooter.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      position: relative;
      top: -1280px;
      left: 550px;
      width: 1025px;
    height: 330px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: justify
        }
```

Comment: please provide some html & css code

Comment: What causes it will be a combination of your HTML and CSS most probably. I'd suggest trying to create a minimum working example by cutting bits out of your page to find out which bit in particular is causing it. This may of course allow you to fix your own problem. But we will really need your CSS and HTML to determine what is wrong...

Comment: I'm putting money on un-cleared floats

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Divs are all closed.

[Validate your code](http://validator.w3.org/) and use a css debugger to make sure all floats are cleared.

Answer (score 0):

if your working with more relative elements and positioning(however) them you should remember that their static point (with width and height) contains. and if you put another element beneath it will be all their height down the page